# Inheriting off an active record model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

I was hoping I could inherit off an activerecord model, and use the subclass as I could the parent class. This does not appear to be the case, the AR relationships do not appear to work for the subclass.

```
class Manager < User
  belongs_to :shop
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :managers
end

class PremiumShop < Shop
end
```

and

```
@premium_shop = manager.shop # Finds the shop.
@premium_shop = manager.premium_shop # Does not find the shop, NilClass:Class error
```

Is it possible to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shop` method exists for some instance of the `Manager` class because of the association you defined through the `belongs_to`. You have no `premium_shop` method defined on your `Manager` model, thus the `NilClass` error.

If you want to define such an association for the `PremiumShop` class, you must explicitly specify this.

```
belongs_to :premium_shop, class_name: "PremiumShop", foreign_key: :shop_id
```

Depending on your needs, you might also consider researching "rails single table inheritance".

Comment: I don't think you need `class_name: "PremiumShop"` in this case, it's guessed from the association name `:premium_shop`, or?